# Bootstrap progress bar; 1% not possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See http://www.bootply.com/cGT4QMnUZy

The 1% fill looks more like 10%. What's wrong here?

```
<div class="progress progress-striped sm active" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px;width:200px">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 1%;">
        <span class="sr-only">1% Complete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do what JordanD suggests or change the aria-valuenow to a decimal. aria-valuenow="1.0"

Comment: See [**Notes**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) "Progress bars representing low single digit percentages, as well as 0%, include a min-width: 20px; for legibility."

Comment: @Adherence Credit to you for my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of fixing your problem.

1. Removing the `aria-valuenow="1"`
2. Changing it to a decimal value `aria-valuenow="1.0"` (thanks @Adherence)

View both ways in the demo.
[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/PFkxbPT2CP)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the attribute **aria-valuenow** (not 1) and just use the attribute **width** in the **style**.

bootstrap has this rule:

```
    .progress-bar[aria-valuenow="1"], .progress-bar[aria-valuenow="2"] {
        min-width: 30px;
    }
```

so bootstrap force the width 30px in these cases...